# GAC and explicit references

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, gac

I am using a third party assembly A referencing another assembly B.

Project C has an explicit reference to B pointing to Nuget package containing B.

Test project is referencing C as a project reference.

Locally I have assembly B in GAC. Build server doesn't have B in GAC.

Both local and server builds don't have B assembly in a test project output.
I can understand that local build would not copy assemblies located in GAC. But I'm still confused why this is ommited on the server?

Test project runs fine locally, but fails on the server because of a missing B.dll.

Comment: Using the GAC on your dev machine or a build server is a mistake.  If used at all, it should only be done on the user's machine.  The trouble caused is plentiful, in this case it fails on the server because the Copy Local property of the assembly reference in the project is False.  Using a different .csproj file on the server just to work around this problem is another drastic mistake you never want to make.  Stop using the GAC.

Comment: Build server doesn't use GAC. The fact that it is used on client machines is accidental (corporate stuff).

Comment: You appear to be missing the point, the problem is that you use it on your dev machine.  Don't do that.